# Google places on Mapbox map

Tags: privacy, mapbox, google-places

I want to add Google places to the Mapbox map on my site. I don't pre-fetch, fetch or store them in any database. Is it possible to use the API to post the places on my custom map or am I violating Google Maps terms of use?

Answer (score 6):

This would break the [Google Places Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/places/policies)

> If your application displays Places API data on a map, that map must be provided by Google.

You might want to use the [Foursquare API](https://developer.foursquare.com/) instead.

Comment: showing data of foursquare api does not violate Google Maps TOS?